# Accessing string from Enum in switch case

Tags: android, enums

I need to compare enums, but note sure how to access them. I get live events which are string. I need to compare it with the set of set of strings to do necessary action. I tried to use enum but its not working

```
public enum Type {

    TYPE_ONE("event/one");
    TYPE_TWO("event/two");

    private Type(String mType){
        this.mType = mType;
    }
    private final String mType;

    public String getType(){return mType;}
}
```

I am trying to compare in Switch/Case:

```
 switch (event.getType()){
                                case Type.TYPE_ONE.getType():  // says "Constant expression required"
                                    Do something:
                                 case Type.TYPE_TWO.getType(): //  says "Constant expression required"
                                    Do something;
                            }
```

Comment: You can't do that. You'll need to resolve the string to the enum first, then use the enum in switch/case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your enum

```
public enum Type {

    TYPE_ONE("event/one");
    TYPE_TWO("event/two");

    private Type(String mType){
        this.mType = mType;
    }
    private final String mType;

    public String getType(){return mType;}

    //Provide the event type and get back the match Type enum
    public Type getTypeFromStringType(String type) {
       for (Type t : Type.values()) {
          if (type.equals(t.getType()) {
             return t;
          }
       }
       return null
    }
}
```

and your method

```
//You have to switch on an enum value
switch (getTypeFromStringType(event.getType())){
   case Type.TYPE_ONE; 
      break;
   case Type.TYPE_TWO;
      break;
}
```

Comment: event is a live event, event.getType() will return a string event/one

Comment: You cant. resolve the enum to a string and go from there. I dont think you understand what exactly you are doing.

Comment: Thanks in the case statement I used Type.TYPE_ONE: I get an error saying "An enum switch case label must be the unqualified name of an enumeration constant"

Comment: Sorry I got it, the case label should be TYPE_ONE. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

How would you like the abstract method?

```
public enum Type {
    TYPE_ONE("event/one"){
        @Override
        public String getType(){return mType;}
    },
    TYPE_TWO("event/two"){
        @Override
        public String getType(){return mType;}
    };

    private final String mType;
    abstract public String getType();
    private Type(String mType){
        this.mType = mType;
    }
}
```

If you want to use String for switch like following, we need to use JDK 7. When we use the version of Java, we must select target API 19 (Kitkat).

```
String hoge = "hoge";
switch (hoge) {
case "hoge":
  break;
default:
  break;
}
```

So I recommend you to do the following;

```
Type type = Type.TYPE_TWO;
switch (type) {
case TYPE_ONE:
  break;
case TYPE_TWO:
  break;
default:
  break;
}
```

By the way, the method is accessible like this;

```
Type type = Type.TYPE_TWO;
String strType = type.getType();
if (strType.equals("event/two")) {/*do something*/}
```

Comment: This is way better and a feature i only recently found out about. I'm mobile and couldnt remember the right way to do it though so I didnt mention it.

Comment: I have like 20 enums, do you think this way is better?? If yes, how will I access from the switch/case?